# I am trying to use Database Inspector in Android Studio. showing my application database (showed in the image) as "closed". Android

Tags: android, android-room

I am facing an issue with the database.

### Issue

> When I open the application it shows the database is closed and but when the application goes on onDestroy state destroying the application it is showing the data present in the database.

- [Room database Image when it's showing "closed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdRIX.png)
- [Room database Image when it's showing "data" in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddA1L.png)

Comment: You can use device file explorer to copy the database and use an sqlite tool, such as DB Browser for SQlite, SQlite Studio, Navicat for SQlite (remember to also copy the -wal file if it exists).

Comment: its because the database instance remains closed in the first scenario. and in the second scenario the DB instance remains open that's why the two occurs